# how to expand the dplyr::tibble with the column contain list of list?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

Here is what I have and what I want:

```r
what_i_have <- dplyr::tibble(
    col_str = "abc",
    col_int = 1,
    col_ls = list(list(
        c(l1 = "1", l2 = "3", l3 = "5"),
        c(l1 = "2", l2 = "4", l3 = "6")
    ))
)

what_i_want <- dplyr::tibble(
    col_str = "abc",
    col_int = 1,
    col_ls = list(
        c(l1 = "1", l2 = "3", l3 = "5"),
        c(l1 = "2", l2 = "4", l3 = "6")
    )
)
```

`what_i_have` looks like this

```
r$> what_i_have                                             
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  col_str col_int col_ls    
  <chr>     <dbl> <list>    
1 abc           1 <list [2]>
```

`what_i_want` looks like this

```
r$> what_i_want                                             
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  col_str col_int col_ls   
  <chr>     <dbl> <list>   
1 abc           1 <chr [3]>
2 abc           1 <chr [3]>
```

How to turn `what_i_have` to `what_i_want`? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `unnest` from `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

what_i_have %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(col_ls))
```

```
  col_str col_int col_ls   
  <chr>     <dbl> <list>   
1 abc           1 <chr [3]>
2 abc           1 <chr [3]>
```